# Getting the warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] in the while_loop function

Tags: c++

Can anybody tell me how I should fix this error? I cannot print the numbers of 10 to 19 individually.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int while_loop(int a)
{
    a = 10;
    while (a < 20)
    {
        a++ ;
        return a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a, result;
    result = while_loop(a);
    cout << "The result of while_loop is : " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is not perfect in this case:

```cpp
int while_loop(int a)
{
    a = 10;
    while (a < 20)
    {
        a++ ;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Since you set a initially to 10, this loop will always terminate (after exactly one iteration). However, in the general case, a while loop will run multiple times or never, and that means that you need to add a `return` statement after the loop.

The code you have written does not use the loop, as it always returns 11 due to the unconditional `return a;` inside your loop. What you want is probably:

```
    while (a < 20)
    {
        a++;
    }
    return a;
```

Also, your main function passes an uninitialized value to your loop function:

```
    int a, result; // change that to int a = 10
    result = while_loop(a);
```

and then you can remove the `a = 10` from inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

#### Mistake 1

When you wrote:

```
 int a, result;
 result = while_loop(a);//UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
```

The variables `a` and `result` have **indeterminate value** since they are of built in type(in local scope) and you haven't initialized them. And using these uninitialized variables leads to **undefined behavior**. So `while_loop(a)` leads to undefined behavior.

To **solve** this you should initialize `a` to `10` as shown below.

```
int a =10, result;//INITIALIZED a to 10
result = while_loop(a);
```

#### Mistake 2

Inside the `while_loop` function if the condition  `while (a < 20)` is not met then the control flow will not encounter any `return` statement and so you get the mentioned warning.

To **solve** this you can move the `return a;` outside `while` loop as shown below:

```
int while_loop(int a)
{
    //a = 10;//NO NEED FOR THIS
    while (a < 20)
    {
        a++ ;
        
    }
    return a;//return moved outside while
}
```

#### Corrected Program

So the modified program looks like:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int while_loop(int a)
{
    //a = 10;NO NEED FOR THIS
    while (a < 20)
    {
        a++ ;
        
    }
    return a;//return MOVED OUTSIDE while
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10, result;//INITIALIZE a to 10
    result = while_loop(a);
    cout << "The result of while_loop is : " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```